# How to include empty xml elements in SOAP request using WCF?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

I have to consume a `Java` web service. The signature of service method is

```
public bool UpsertEmployee(Employee employe);
```

The problem is when the `SOAP` is generated, for the properties with null value the coresponding `XML` elements are not included in request. The result is:

```
...
<Employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <firstName>Jhonny</firstName>
</Employee>
```

And I want to be:

```
...
<Employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <firstName>Jhonny</firstName>
  <lastName/>
</Employee>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Can I set a property before mehod invocation?

```
var client= new EmployeeServiceClient();;
// Can I do something here to accoplish my goal?    
client.UpsertEmployee(new Employee{
    id = "1",
    firstname = "Jhonny"
});
```

The generated `Employee` class code is

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.36366")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "urn:mve.go.all.mdg.vendor")]
public partial class Employee : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string idField;

    private string firstNameField;

    private string lastNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 1)]
    public string firstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.firstNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.firstNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("firstName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 3)]
    public string lastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lastNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lastNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("lastName");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot modify the file code because in the future it is posible to need an update on the service reference.

Comment: It may be result of `Employee` definition. `Employee` is probably Your custom class, so it should be defined as `DataContract` and its properties as `DataMember`s. In `DataMember`, there's a setting named `EmitCustomValue` (true by default). It controls if empty values are included in the SOAP.  For more information, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx . Take a look at `Employee` class definition and verify that `EmitDefaultValue` is *not* set to `false`.

Comment: The service is written in `Java`, I have checked the file `Reference.cs` (by pressing `f12` on service class name) and there is no `DataContract ` attrribute, instead all properties have the `XmlElementAttribute` attribute, and I cannot modify the file code because in the future it is posible to need an update on the service reference.

Comment: Need to see the `Employee` class to be sure, but setting `lastName = ""` should work.  Both c# xml serializers serialize an empty string as an empty element and completely skip null strings by default.

Comment: I have updated my question. I added the autogenerated code for `Employee` class. The class resulted after t added the reference to `Java` web service.

Answer (score 3):

Your class is marked with [`XmlSerializer` attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx) so it appears you are using that serializer.

Your problem is that the `lastName` property is `null`.  As explained in *[Xsi:nil Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69(v=vs.110).aspx)*:

> When serializing objects into an XML document: If the `XmlSerializer` class encounters a null reference for an object corresponding to an XML element, it either generates an element that specifies `xsi:nil="true"` or leaves the element out entirely, depending on whether a `nillable="true"` setting applies.

Thus, by default, when `lastName` is null no element is emitted.  And if you were to set [`[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable(v=vs.110).aspx) you would instead get

```
<Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>1</id>
  <firstName>Jhonny</firstName>
  <lastName xsi:nil="true" />
</Employee>
```

Which is **not** what you want (and in any event you cannot change the auto-generated code).

Instead you need to initialize `lastName` to the empty string:

```
var employee = new Employee
{
    id = "1",
    firstName = "Jhonny",
    lastName = "",
};
```

And then the following XML will be generated:

```
<Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>1</id>
  <firstName>Jhonny</firstName>
  <lastName />
</Employee>
```

Or, since the auto-generated code does not have a default constructor, you could add one yourself in a separate `partial class` code file.  Since it is independent from the auto-generated code file it will not gen overwritten when you regenerate the generated code:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.firstName = this.lastName = this.id = "";
    }
}
```